# How To get Actual Used Range in Rows and Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel worksheet which has 360 Rows and 65 columns "Filled" with Actual data but the when I try to get the `.UsedRange` I am getting More than 600 Rows and 100 columns as Used range!
Can you please let me know how I can Remove/Delete the empty Used ranges anf only retrive the actual range data?
I tried this way but getting "Type MisMatch" error on `Rows("deleteted:all").Select` part

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
With ws
   LastRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   deleteted = LastRow + 1
   all = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

   With .UsedRange
      Rows("deleteted:all").Select
      Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End With
End With
```

Comment: Which Version Of Excel You are Using?

Comment: @sagar Version is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line of code

```
Rows("deleteted:all").Select
```

to

```
Rows(deleteted & ":" & all).Select
```

And you should get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Another Method

`Syntex`:

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Thanks Sagar, but I have issue on slection part not delete! remember? I said I am getting mismach error on Rows("deleteted:all").Select